# Understanding python's memory model

Tags: python, memory

Consider the following log:

> >>> y  = 20000
>   >>> id(y)
>   36638928
>   >>> y = 1000000
>   >>> id(y)
>   36639264

As you can see, after changing the value of `y`, it's id changed as well.
Does it mean that `int` is immutable? what is happening behind the scenes?

Thanks!

Comment: yes it's immutable, it just affected a new variable to the name `y`. Feel free to google these things online, there are plenty of resources online already..

Comment: You did not change the value stored in `y`, but assigned a new value to `y`. This would change the `id` even if that value was mutable.

Comment: I recommend reading http://bit.ly/pynames (to every python programmer ever, really).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that `int`'s are immutable. On the right hand side of the assignments are *different* objects, that's what matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, integers are immutable. What you need to realize is that:

1. A variable is simply a name which you use to reference an object.
2. `20000` and `1000000` are two *unique* integer objects.  This means that they will never share the same memory address simultaneously.

In simple terms, when you execute this line:

```
y = 20000
```

two things happen:

1. An integer object `20000` is created in the object space.
2. A name `y` is created in the namespace and pointed to that object.

When you execute this one:

```
y = 1000000
```

two more things happen:

1. A new integer object `1000000` is created in the object space.
2. The name `y` is changed to point to that object instead of `20000`.

Comment: I saw what you did there!

Comment: this makes it sounds like `x=10`, `y=10` then `id(x) != id(y)` which is not true, there is only one occurrence of each integer and both x and y reference it.

Comment: @cmd: that's sort of an implementation detail, `int`'s are occasionally interned, but the circumstances under which they are interned is not a defined part of the language;  for example; on my machine (cpython 2.7.6) `1000 is 1000` but `1000 is not (999 + 1)`

Comment: To be pedantic, 20000 and 100000 could end up in the same place in memory at different times, if whichever one was there first was no longer referenced and got deallocated.

Comment: It is not "given the integer object as a value" - the correct phrase is _"A name `y` is created in the namespace and is pointed to the object `20000` that is created in the object space"_ as this is actually what is happening, and a unique distinction in Python. Variables are not "boxes to hold things" (that's why they are called _names_ and not _variables_ in Python).

Comment: Well, I'll add a little more detail.  However, I was trying to keep it very simple for the OP.  I think a super detailed answer will confuse him even more.